# websockets do not work when assigned to global var

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I use websockets along with javascript and html5

I have the following code.

```
    <input type="text" onFocus=" so = new websocket('ws://localhost:1234');" onBlur="so.close();" onKeyUp="keyup();" >

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var so; //this is global...

//wait a little (user stops typing)    
   function keyup(){
if (timeout) {clearTimeout(timeout);}    
    timeout = setTimeout(lookup, 250);
}



    function lookup(){
      //it's global, so use it right away
      so.onopen = function(){
      //send data to server to get responce...
```

So, websockets open/close if user clicks/or not a textfield. User types something on textfield. The value of textfield is sended to the server, a query is executed and if there are matching results, they render on the screen of the user.

If I click on the text field I see in the console "connected" and if I click anyware else I see "closed normally", as I should. That's ok.

But when I type letteres to the textfield, to send data to server, nothing is sended. I see nothing in the console. I see no errors.

What am I missing? It's like `so.onopen` never get executed.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you recreate the socket but don't bind the onopen event handler.

On focus, you should call a function doing both : create the websocket and bind the onopen event handler :

```
<input id=someid type="text" onBlur="so.close();" >

<script type='text/javascript'>
var so, field = document.getElementById('someid');
field.onfocus = function(){
    so = new websocket('ws://localhost:1234');
    so.onopen = function(){
         // do things
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but, the `onopen` has to be in another function, I cant change the structure of my code. The weird thing is that even if I just put `var so = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");` as global at the start of javascript and then `so.ononpen` in the function, still does not executed. I dont get it...

Comment: There's nothing weird. You bind onopen on a different socket because you don't insure the order of the instructions. You *have* to change the structure of your code. By the way please notice how I could instill some sanity by removing the inlined JavaScript.

Comment: I just edited my question. Sorry for that. Hope you understand my problem better. I did `field.onfocus = function(){
function keyup(){...` And I get `keyup function is not defined` error.

Comment: @slevin `so.onopen` will be executed once.  If, as seems likely, you don't bother to set it until after it would have been executed, you've missed it.  You _must_ bind onopen right after creating the socket, or you're taking the chance that you'll miss it and it won't execute.